# Progress bar inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I need to add progress to table cell background. Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kedctfmj/3/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>
            value2
            <div class="bg" style="width: 20%"/>
        </td>
        <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>value4</td>
        <td>
            value5
            <div class="bg" style="width: 30%"/>
        </td>
        <td>value6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 300px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
    position: relative;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #8ef;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Closest I was able to achieve is with z-index: -1. But this doesn't play well with tr's background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a very little opacity to `tr` elements (so that new stacking context is created for `tr` elements) and then `z-index: -1` will work as expected:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    opacity: .999;
}
.bg {
    /* ... */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kedctfmj/5/

Another problem that potentially may cause troubles in IE is self-closing `<div />` tags. This is not valid syntax, it should have closing tags `</div>`:

```
<div class="bg" style="width: 20%"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered changing the opacity of the .bg item so that the value can still be displayed?

Using the code from your fiddle:

```
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #8ef;
    opacity: 0.5;
    /*z-index: -1;*/ }
```

Hope this helps...

-- Lance